# Android - Google maps Api v2 - Authentication error

Tags: android, dictionary

After a lot of research to resolve my issue, I have to ask. Everything is set up but the map won't show. The error is:

```
08-16 20:31:49.473: E/Google Maps Android API(10864): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I am running the Map on Debug mode (I've also tried by installing the .apk into the device and running it) and the same thing happens - no Map.

- I have checked Api key

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ... >

    <permission
        android:name="com.my_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.my_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        ... >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCEH*************************" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Activity**

public class Home extends Activity {

```
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: In Google Api console, does billing need to be set up for it to authenticate Api key?

Comment: No, billing doesn't need to be set up.

Comment: In Api console, which Services need to be activated for Android Google Maps v2? I did something and the maps started working, then it went away again. I think Services are related to this.

Comment: In API console you only need to activate the *service* "Google Maps **Android** API v2". At next, you must create a new *Android key* to get API access. To create a new API key you must enter your SHA1 certificate and your correct package name (separated by a semicolon). Did you enter these things correctly?

Comment: At the moment, I have activated these services:
- Google Maps Android API v2
- Google Maps API v2
- Google Maps Engine API

Then, I created the API key again and the Maps worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate these **Services** in the Google Console:

- Google Maps Android API v2

Then, **recreate** the API key and the Maps should work - they did for me.

Comment: You only need the first one, "Google Maps Android API v2".

Comment: Any luck? I'm facing the same issue, a white canvas. Recreated the API-key, followed the answers on stackoverflow, but no luck..

Comment: @Diego For me, it was the `Google Maps Android API v2` `Services` which needed to be activated. I activated it, then recreated the API double and triple checking the SHA1 key and Package name. Then fired up my App and it worked. Make sure that you completely uninstall the app from your device before running it again. This will ensure no glitches or garbage is left over. Let me know how it goes. I'll help as much as I can.

Comment: Are you running it from Eclipse or installing the app through adb install? Somehow if I try the last one it crashes, but no map still.

Comment: I use my Samsung S3 device as a test/debug device. I don't use AVD's they're way too slow. I plug in my S3 using USB cable, in my phone's settings, I enable Developer + debug mode under Settings, and when I click Run on eclipse, my Phone shows up as an Active device.

Answer (score 1):

It's an authentication issue, it's likely you haven't setup your API key correctly, using your SHA1 fingerprint.

Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key)

Comment: The SHA1 is correct and so is the package. It's the Google console. It takes time and the order you activate the Service and create the API key affects it. Correct order is: Activate appropriate Service, then create the API then run the App. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your manifest.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"></meta-data>
```

Also check that the Consent Screen (on Google Developer Console Website > Settings) has your email address and product name.